# Should I add something to use a usePanGestureHandler() function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, swipe

I'm not very familiar with gestures, so I'm trying to do a swipe left and right with the help of a guide. Dude in that guide types `const { gestureHandler } = usePanGestureHandler();` But that doesn't work with my code. I imported `import { PanGestureHandler } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';` but that still doesn't work. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's your problem but you import from https://github.com/wcandillon/react-native-redash

import { usePanGestureHandler } from 'react-native-redash';